# fprintf for heterogeneous struct

Tags: c++, io

Is there a simple way to concatenate all of the `fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[x]);` expressions into a small number of expressions?

Appreciate any other suggestions.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>

    // fprintfQuestion.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    // add _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE  to Properties \ C\C++ \ Preprocessor \  Preprocessor Definitions

    struct mod
    {
        char    name[32];
        int     dateStart;
        int     dateEnd;
    };
```

The struct mod is an abbreviated version of the struct used in a GUI editor for the game for which I'm an apprentice developer. The full struct includes about 20 variables. Objects from this struct correspond to "script modules" used by the game's computer-opponent, and which can be randomly or statically assigned to specific scenarios in the game by scenario designers.

The goal of the exercise I'm engaged in at present is to develop a "loader" application that can transfer data between the .dat files the editor works with and .csv files that humans can manipulate in spreadsheets. Most of the scenario designers are not programmers.

```
    int main()
    {
        FILE     *pFile, *qFile;
        int      cnt = 0, n = 0;
        char     str[40]; //1328
        mod      mod[3]; //2000
        long     bytes = 1328; // first record of 0 to 1327 is blank

    pFile = fopen("W:\\User\\dir\\sourcefile.dat", "rb");
    qFile = fopen("W:\\User\\dir\\targetfile.csv", "a");

    for (cnt = 0; cnt < 3; cnt++)
       {
        fseek(pFile, bytes, SEEK_SET);
          for (n = 0; n < 40; n++)
             {
               str[n] = getc(pFile);
             };
          memmove(mod+cnt, str, 40);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[0]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[1]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[2]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[3]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[4]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[5]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[6]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[7]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[8]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[9]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[10]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[11]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[12]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[13]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[14]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[15]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[16]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[17]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[18]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[19]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[20]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[21]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[22]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[23]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[24]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[25]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[26]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[27]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[28]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[29]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[30]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c,", mod[cnt].name[31]);
          fprintf(qFile, "%.6i,", mod[cnt].dateStart);
          fprintf(qFile, "%.6i,", mod[cnt].dateEnd);
          fprintf(qFile,"\n");
          bytes = (bytes + 1328);
    };

    fclose(pFile);
    fclose(qFile);
    std::cout << "Type any key to quit. \n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, there are no null-terminated records in the data; my examination of the .dat files with HexEdit does not suggest as much to me.

A typical row of output in the .csv that this code generates might be:

> Attack Orleans Rgt,281012,291228

Corresponding to the name of the script, the date it can start (12 Oct 1428) and the date it can end (28 Dec 1429).

Comment: Please verify your indentation. The easiest way to post code is to paste it, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.

Comment: What does a `struct mod` represent? What are you really aiming to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Is there some reason a simple loop wouldn't work? `for (i=0; i<32; i++) fprintf(qfile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[i]);`

Comment: Thnx for the headsup on the indentation 200_success. There are .dat files each with around 2 million bytes of data of varying types. The struct I present here is an abbreviated version of the actual struct used in the editor (the source code we do not have). These .dat files are used by an gui "editor" application by developers and "modders" building scenarios for the game. The goal is to enable full i/o between .dat files and .csv files.

Comment: @JerryCoffin that is something I considered trying, but I wanted to see if there are obscure formatting conventions for fprintf that might do it. As an example, I had no idea there was such at thing as the "+cnt" as a way to specify the offset in:  memmove(mod+cnt, str, 40);

Comment: @DicheBach: I don't think such a thing exists. If it does, it's sufficiently obscure that I'd probably avoid it anyway.

Comment: @DicheBach Can you explain why you use `"%-1.1c"` as your format string?  Doesn't that just print one character?  You specify left alignment, minimum one character, and precision one character, but I don't see how that is any different than just `"%c"` when we are talking about printing single characters?  Perhaps you could show us an example of a line of output.

Comment: @JS1 You're right! It produces identical output with "%c" as for "%-1.1.c"  Thanks for pointing that out! I like building better C syntax skills. Here is an example of one line of output: Attack Orlean 14th Regt,281012,291228

Comment: @JerryCoffin that worked: you should post this as an answer if you want  for (i = 0; i < 31; i++) { fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c", mod[cnt].name[i]); }; fprintf(qFile, "%-1.1c,", mod[cnt].name[31]);  It requires at least two lines in order to add the comma at the end of the string, but that is much better than 32 lines! Thanks

Comment: Any good reason why you are using C-style strings and IO in a C++ project?

Comment: @D. Jurcau the source code traces back to a game engine that was pure C code in the 1980s. Several games have been built onto it. We tried using some of the newer "managed code" io functions and encountered difficulties, so have resorted to these. It is certainly possible there are ways that the newer stuff could be made to work with the game. But at my skill level, and my mentor rusty in C and distracted by his day job, it would probably be too time consuming. I would be curious to know however, what objective downsides there are to using C-style grammar, syntax and 'vocabulary.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Merge all `fprintf()`s into a single one

You could try merging all of your `fprintf()` calls into this single call:

```
fprintf(qFile, "%.32s,%.6i,%.6i,\n", mod[cnt].name, mod[cnt].dateStart,
        mod[cnt].dateEnd);
```

The `%.32s` specifier means "print a string up to 32 characters long".  From the example output you showed in the comments, I think that this would work for you.  If you don't need a trailing comma at the end of the line, you could remove it.  (Your code had it there but your example didn't so I left it in).

#### Use `fread()`

Instead of this loop and `memmove()`:

```
    for (n = 0; n < 40; n++)
         {
           str[n] = getc(pFile);
         };
    memmove(mod+cnt, str, 40);
```

You could use one call to fread:

```
    fread(&mod[cnt], 1, sizeof(mod[cnt]), pFile);
```

You might want to `static_assert` that `sizeof(struct mod) == 40` somewhere, since your code seems to depend on that.

Comment: `"%.32s"` assumes that `name` is a null-terminated, which the author has not confirmed. (I've downvoted the question for lack of clarity.)

Comment: As far as I know, none of it is null-terminated. How would I know if it is for certain? @JS1: thanks for the suggestions! I will check it out.

Comment: @200_success Even if `name` is not null-terminated, `"%.32s"` will still only print the first 32 characters, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It could also contain internal nulls, though.

Comment: Yep, those changes worked JS1. I'm tempted to post the revised version of it, but not sure if that is poor etiquette or if I would do it in an answer or as an edit to the original post. Anyway thanks to everyone for responding. I've learned more about C/C++ and that is always a good thing! :)

Comment: @200_success I'm almost positive there are no nulls inside the strings that correspond to name[32]. These are names given to the modules that correspond to the 'mod' objects, so they are only common characters (numbers, letters, punctuation, space).

Comment: @200_success Ah I see what you mean.  Well, in the case of internal nulls it would require a loop, but hopefully the file format is more sane than that.

Comment: In response to my query "hey Joe, none of these records are null-terminated are they?" My mentor says: "This is a "data file" not a "text file" or a "c string" file. "data files" do not contain any formatting. As "polish" when you get done, you can add a hard coded, comma delimited header row." He has been a programmer for about 35 years so, big picture, he tends to know what he is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is bad etiquette, but the help I've received has been so decisive and clear, I wanted to post the "revised" version of the code based on the suggestions received above, and especially the accepted answer by JS1

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

// fprintfQuestion.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// add _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE  to Properties \ C\C++ \ Preprocessor \  Preprocessor Definitions

struct mod
{
    char    name[32];
    int     dateStart;
    int     dateEnd;
};

static_assert (sizeof(mod) == 40, "Struct mod is != 40.");

int main()
{
    FILE     *pFile, *qFile;
    int      cnt = 0, n = 0, i = 0;
    char     str[40]; //1328
    mod      mod[3]; //2000
    long     bytes = 1328; // first record of 0 to 1327 is blank

    pFile = fopen("W:\\User\\dir\\sourcefile.dat", "rb");
    qFile = fopen("W:\\User\\dir\\targetfile.csv", "a");

    for (cnt = 0; cnt < 3; cnt++)
    {
        fseek(pFile, bytes, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&mod[cnt], 1, sizeof(mod[cnt]), pFile);
        fprintf(qFile, "%.32s,%.6i,%.6i,\n", mod[cnt].name, mod[cnt].dateStart, 
        mod[cnt].dateEnd);
        bytes = (bytes + 1328);
    };

    fclose(pFile);
    fclose(qFile);
    std::cout << "Type any key to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The revised version might be a good candidate for a new question.  There is still a lot that can be improved here, if you're interested.

Comment: @Edward Cool, yeah. Let the suggestions ensue!